# htaccess mod_rewrite : Redirect root to folder

Tags: .htaccess

When I call the **root** of my webpage I got error 403:

**Forbidden
You don't have permission to access / on this server.**

My htaccess looks like:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/$

RewriteRule (.*) dir/file.php

Options -Indexes
```

**How can I redirect the root to a folder, with no error 403?**
And without loosing the functionality of

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
```

Answer (score 1):

To redirect **everything**, except:

- existing files
- existing dirs with an index.php in it

.htaccess content:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule (.*) /special/index.php
RewriteRule ^$ /special/index.php [QSA,L]
Options -Indexes
```

Answer (score 0):

Most likely (based on my experience) you do not have default file that will be executed when directory is requested.

1) You may need to add this directive into your `.htaccess`. This will tell Apache to execute index.php when requesting directory.

```
DirectoryIndex index.php
```

2) Make sure you do have `index.php` present in such directory, otherwise you will see the 403 error.

What exactly do you mean by "How can I redirect the root to a folder"? Here is the rule that will execute `/special/index.php` file if you request root folder of your site (e.g. `http://example.com/`

```
RewriteRule ^$ /special/index.php [QSA,L]
```

---

**UPDATE:**

```
RewriteRule ^mydir/(index\.php)?$ http://www.example.com/ [R=301,QSA,NC]
```

This will tell Apache to **redirect** (change URL in a browser's address bar) from `http://www.example.com/mydir/index.php` or `http://www.example.com/mydir/` to `http://www.example.com/`

```
RewriteRule ^$ mydir/index.php [QSA,L]
```

This will tell Apache to execute `/mydir/index.php` when you hit the root folder (e.g. `http://www.example.com/`) without changing URL in address bar.

If you want it to work together with your existing rules you will have to put these 2 rules above other -- for example, right after `RewriteBase /`